# C# WinForm chart data wont display

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, .net-6.0

So I'm having a really weird problem in C# WindForm. I've tried to create a chart. In the area where the chart itself should exist, the problem is that it displays no data. It just looks like that:
[image]

That's my code:

```
        int questionsAmount = setData.questionsAmount;

        var dates = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach(var item in setData.dates)
        {
            dates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item));
        }

        int[] records = setData["records"].ToObject<int[]>();

        Series series = new Series("records");
        series.Points.DataBindXY(dates, records);
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;

        chart = new Chart();
        chart.Name = set.title;
        chart.Series.Add(series);

        chart.Series["records"].SetDefault(true);
        chart.Series["records"].Enabled = true;
        chart.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;

        Controls.Add(chart);

        Refresh();
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are not dropping the chart from the toolbox it doesn't have any of the things it needs before it can work. You need to create them al in code as well: Start with a ChartArea!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. First, because we cannot read the entire code, I cannot sure the data generating process is working well. As your picture, the chart control is added. Maybe you can add breakpoint on "*series.Points.DataBindXY(dates, records);*" and check whether the data is ready or not.

FYI, another probable issue is you need to do UI operation in main thread (UI thread) if you didn't.

Hope these can help you.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for replying. The data generation does works correctly (I've checked it in debugging).
I'm not sure which UI operation I should do in the main thread. I'm kind of new to charting in windforms...